# How to charge ether from user and track that in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I need to add integration of Ethereum charging to my project.

I've done that with Bitcoin. It was easy. I just create a new receiver address for each payment, but it doesn't work with Ethereum.

Had somebody done that before?

Comment: What language are you in and what libraries are you using? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Where did the trouble start? (creating an address? receiving the funds? etc)

Comment: Language doesn't matter. I want to allow user to pay by ETH in my app and I need to know that exactly this user payed this ETH value.